# Form Background Image Tearing - C# - WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, background

I was making a Form application on Visual Studio 2019 (Windows Forms) and then noticed the image was tearing when I was resizing the form. How can I fix it? Should I change one of the properties of the `TabControl` control?

Here's a photo showing what happened:
[Background Image Tearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdxt2.png)

Note: the image seen in the photo is the background image of the `Form` control

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to override **CreateParams** method.

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;
            return cp;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.CreateParams;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what does this do ?